# Single link query where clause to take only `n` of each type from a single model/table

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Having a table `Entities` with a column `type` (between other columns) how can I select only `n` entities from type `A` and `m` entities from type `b` in a single linq query where clause? Is it possible?

I am looking for something like this:

```
var x = from s in db.Entities
        where s.type == `A` && (????) < n 
           || s.type == `B` && (????) < m 
        select s
```

Current solution with combined queries:

```
var x = entities.Where(e => e.type == `A`).Take(n).Union(
        entities.Where(e => e.type == `B`).Take(m));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GroupBy`:

```
var x = db.Entities.GroupBy(x => x.type)
                   .Where(g => g.Key == "A" || g.Key == "B")
                   .SelectMany(g => g.Key == "A" ? g.Take(n) : g.Take(m));
```

But I don't know why you don't like your `Union`-based solution - it should result in just one query sent to the database anyway.

Comment: I was trying to create a `Func<entity -> bool>` to encapsulate the where clause when I realized I couldt do that. Then, I just want to see other people solutions.